# How do you compare the output of a command with a string variable?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

```
[root@ip-10-10-61-178 ~]# cat if.sh 
#!/bin/bash

VPCCIDR=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4 | cut -c 1-5`
```

I am trying to achieve the following with bash but am having trouble:

1. curl the AWS instance data URL and return the beginning of the local IP. e.g 10.10 for test or 10.20 for prod
2. If the output of the curl equals to the variable called $TESTENV then print "This is Test" else if it is equal to the variable called $PRODENV then print "This is Prod. If it matches none then echo "no match".

The problem I have is that my script just echoes "This is Test" regardless of what values I set for TESTENV and PRODENV.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Find out what VPC we are in. e.g 10.10 or 10.50
VPCCIDR=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4 | cut -c 1-5`

TESTENV="10.10"
PRODENV="10.50"

if [ "$VPCCIDDR" != "$TESTENV" ]; then  
echo "This is Test"
elif [ "$VPCCIDDR" != "$PRODENV" ]; then
echo "This is Prod"
else
echo "no match"
fi
```

Comment: do `echo $VPCCIDR` after you initialize to see what is the value

Comment: I added the echo to the script and ran again. Output as follows:      [root@ip-10-10-61-178 ~]# ./if.sh 
10.10
This is Test

Comment: You have a typo. You are setting `VPCCIDR` (one "D"), but testing the value of `VPCCIDDR` (two "D"s).

Comment: Thats a good shout; thanks. What baffles me even more though is that correcting the typo still gives the same results

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
VPCCIDR=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4 | cut -c 1-5)
```

But as noted in the comments, that won't change your script.

> as far as I know in bash command substitution does not technically
>   differ. Well, the $(...) syntax actually allows for more convenient
>   nesting and treats slashes differently as well as improving
>   readability. But no actual functional differencies.

-Zlog (in the ocomments)

A few things to note.

1) I assume that URL returns your IP address. I tested it with this API: `$(curl -s https://api.ipify.org | cut -c 1-5)` and learned that you're returning the FIRST digits of the IP address. Assuming you have a typical prod/dev set up, I would think that you'd want to check the LAST digits of the ip, not the first, but I may be completely wrong about that.

2) Here's where your problem is...

```
if [ "$VPCCIDDR" != "$TESTENV" ]; then  
echo "This is Test"
```

Your conditionals are all freaked up. You're saying.. "if my ip does NOT match the test envireonment, tell the user we're in the test environment." I'm sure you meant to do the opposite. You probably want to do `==` instead of `!=`.

3) Also, you've got the -s flag which prevents errors from displaying. Test the url in the browser to make sure it's not throwing errors.

4) You're using different variables throughout your script. Make sure you're typing your variables the same way everywhere you use them.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. It still just displays "This is Test" no matter what.

Comment: @Adelphia, this is just a change of syntax. Interpreted exactly the same as with backticks in this example. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Zloj, they're not the same thing, but you're right, in this context they are doing the exact same thing.

Comment: @Zloj there you go, a more substantial answer

Comment: @Adelphia thanks. And one more: just as far as I know in bash command substitution does not technically differ. Well, the $(...) syntax actually allows for more convenient nesting and treats slashes differently as well as improving readability. But no actual functional differencies. That may just be mentioned in the first part of your answer. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Zloj, the main differnce is that you can nest commands with $().. consider this.. `$(somecommand | grep $(someother -command))`, you can't do that with backticks, but I will add that tot he answer.

Comment: @Adelphia you can nest with backticks, but you need to escape each consecutive level of nested backticks with the corresponding number of forward slashes.

Comment: oh, didn't know that.

Comment: @Adelphia sorry, I confused forward slash with backslash. That's probably one of the reasons why backticks aren't good.